# Access Excel formulas in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-formula

I need to use `NORMSINV` formula in Excel in my C# code. I dont have any contact with Excel sheet and I am not getting any values from excel. Simply need to use the formula in C# code.

How to acheive this?

Comment: To clarify, you want some C# code that performs the same function as _normsinv_ but without actually using Excel itself?

Comment: yes exactly. Also can that formula be achieved by adding some reference of office tools to my c sharp code in header files??

Comment: You would need to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace - IIRC you'd need to create a spreadsheet in memory and read the answer out of the cells. You'd also need Excel installed on the PC running the code. Recommend you look at the other answer(s) identifying libraries with equivalent functionality

Comment: I am not having excel in the machine and I am not sure excel will be installed or not...

Comment: If you may not have Excel on the machine, you cannot use the Excel functions directly.

Comment: Ok, and is any c sharp code available as an alternate?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the GSL (GNU Scientific Library, written in C). The function which corresponds to the one you're after would be "gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Pinv" I believe.

You can get the GSL here:

http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/gnu/gsl

Details of the function from Excel:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826772

And the corresponding details from the GSL:

http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Gaussian-Distribution.html

(Note: The Standard Normal distribution is also known as the Unit Gaussian distribution)

Comment: I want to use only this function. Thanks a lot i will check and let you know

Comment: I don't really know C#, but as sqrt, pow and M_PI are defined in C99 then the following should work:

public double normsinv(double x)
{
  return (1 / sqrt(M_PI)) * exp(-1 * (pow(x,2)/2));
}

Comment: Apparently M_PI was dropped in C99 actually, you'll also need to define M_PI yourself:

#define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846

Comment: public double Normsinv(double x)
        {
            return (1 / Math.Sqrt(Math.PI)) * Math.Exp(-1 * (Math.Pow(x, 2) / 2));
        }   // This is the equavalent code but i dont know how far its correct

Comment: Apologies, I gave you the PDF of a Normal Distribution, not the CDF; give me a couple of minutes and I'll write in C# the correct method for you.

Comment: if i give a number like 60.00% has to return 0.253 and similarly if i give 70.00% it should return 0.524. This is my requirement. thanks a lot. Cant forget your timely help

Comment: Unfortunately the CDF is quite complex to implement cleanly, I would highly recommend using the GSL.

Comment: Oops then i have no idea on how to implement..Can you please explain in brief.

Comment: Can you try my other answer out and see if it returns the values you're after?

Comment: ya sure.. i am working on it. i will let you know once completed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should calculate an accurate approximation of what you're after.

(Note: I don't program in C# so there might be some syntax errors)

```
public double pdf_norm(double x)
{
  return (1 / Math.Sqrt(Math.PI)) * Math.Exp(-1 * (Math.Pow(x, 2) / 2)); 
}

public double cdf_norm(double x)
{
  double[] bValues = [0.2316419, 0.319381530, −0.356563782, 1.781477937, −1.821255978, 1.330274429];

  double t = 1 / (1 + bValues[0]*x);

  return 1 - pdf_norm(x)*(bValues[1]*t + bValues[2]*Math.Pow(t,2) + bValues[3]*Math.Pow(t,3) + bValues[4]*Math.Pow(t,4) + bValues[5]*Math.Pow(t,5));
}
```

You'd then want to call the function cdf_norm to return the number you want.

Please test it works and let me know. :)

Comment: i have passed 60 as a parameter to pdf_norm and called cdf_norm but i got 0.4963164 but it should have been 0.253

Comment: double doubleNormsinv = cdf_norm(pdf_norm(60));                                      public double pdf_norm(double x)
        {
            return (1 / Math.Sqrt(Math.PI)) * Math.Exp(-1 * (Math.Pow(x/100, 2) / 2));
        }             //Since i am passing percentage value i am dividing it by 100 in Math.Pow

Comment: how about this??http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/impl/misra/normsinv.html

Comment: The input would be 0.6 for 60%, 0.7 for 70% etc, i.e. cdf_norm(0.6); also - that JavaScript function looks like it works, implementing that in C# should be easy enough for you as well.

Comment: That javascript function works only for few numbers like till 70-80% its correctly gives the answer but after that the value is getting reduced for ex: if i give 99.99% it gives 2.4900160235815867 but it should be 3.71

Comment: If i give 0.99 it should return as 3.719 but its not returning that value...any suggestions please? http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/impl/misra/normsinv.html  even in this link  its not correctly returning

Comment: 0.99 should return 2.326 according to Numbers and the JavaScript produces the same result; are you sure you're not meaning to put in 0.9999 which would produce 3.719? Either that or Excel has some strange rounding procedures.